# Why can't Satyrs find Roman Demigods?

Tags: percy-jackson, the-heroes-of-olympus

Satyrs have the abilty to smell Demigods and Monsters alike. Satyrs are also tasked out by Camp Half Blood to go out in the world and find Half Blood Children. They may be discouraged to search in the vicinity of Camp Jupiter just as the Greek Demigods, but why don't they find any roman demigods in the schools they go in?

As far as the Satyrs know there are no Greek/Roman Demigods so I find it highly co-incidental they don't find any Roman Demigods before they find there way to Lupa and then to Camp Jupiter.

Edit: I am talking about Satyrs and Fauns and not Demigods finding each other. After the defeat of Kronos Satyrs went all over the country scrounging for Demigods. Don the Faun showed he could smell Percy's empathy link. Also 2 instances of Greeks meeting Roman are before the Roman demigods knowing their heritage (Thalia and Jason, Percy/Anabeth meeting Reyna/Hylla)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Because of the gods

It was mentioned that after the American Civil War, the gods did everything they could to prevent the two camps from meeting.<sup>1</sup> Logically, this would extend to preventing Greek satyrs from smelling Roman demigods.

---

<sup>1</sup>

> "The answer is dangerous," he warned. "It is something that I swore upon the River Styx never to speak of. After the American Civil War, the gods were so horrified by the toll that it took on their children, that they swore that it would never happen again. The two groups were separated. The gods bent all of their will, wove the Mist as tightly as they could, **to make sure the enemies never remembered each other, never met on their quests, to prevent bloodshed.** This map is from the final dark days of 1864, the last time the two groups fought. We've had some close calls since then. The nineteen sixties were particularly dicey. But we've managed to avoid another civil war - at least so far.

---

Alternative answer:

**They do find them**.

It's entirely possible that they *do* find the Roman demigods. The only reason Jason was different was that he had previously *been* to Camp Jupiter, and knew the gods by their Roman names. Otherwise, a Roman would be indistinguishable, essentially, from the Greek demigods.

Comment: Only relevant quote I could find was that Gods weaved mist to make the demigods forget the camps and iirc "there have been close calls during quests" I am not sure it included Satyrs and I am not sure how would roman demigods smell different from Greeks.

Comment: @Arcane That's the quote I'm referencing.

Answer (score 0):

The satyr found Greek demigods by "scenting" them. The Mist would essentially cover up the scent of the Roman demigods to prevent the two pantheon from mixing. Plus, many Roman demigods stayed in camp or went to the Wolf House to be trained, and thus less were outside of Camp Jupiter.